# File not found from within SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, batch-file, xp-cmdshell

What I am trying to do is the following:
Everyday I get a CSV file that eventually needs to be imported into SQL via Bulk Insert. 
This all has worked great for a long time but recently, one of the columns in the CSV file contains text that needs to be replaced before the bulk insert.

After some searching i found the following code for a BAT-file:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "search=%1"
set "replace=%2"
set "textfile=Input.txt"
set "newfile=Output.txt"
(for /f "delims=" %%i in (%textfile%) do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
))>"%newfile%"
del %textfile%
rename %newfile%  %textfile%
```

Now when i put this bat-file in the directory and double click to run it that works great.
But the problem now is that i want to integrate it in a SQL Stored Procedure I put it in the procedure like this:

```
EXEC master..xp_CMDShell 'E:\FolderName\REPLACE.BAT'
```

When i try to run that i get the message "File not found" in SQL.
Both for the stored procedure as for running it just as a query (under my own credentials, which are admin rights).
Just to be sure i gave the SQL-user also full rights on the specific folder, but that didnt help either.

How can I get this work inside SQL Server?

Comment: Just to be clear, other xp_CMDShell commands in the same stored procedure are running fine so its not a problem with xp_CMDShell not being enabled

Comment: Does the "E" drive actual driver or shared folder(I mean mapped)?

Comment: you'll have to replace E:\ with the UNC path to the folder if you're running it outside of the server environment

Comment: Isn't backslash ( \ ) an escape character in SQL? Try replacing each  \  with  \\  or with `/` like this: EXEC master..xp_CMDShell 'E:\\FolderName\\REPLACE.BAT'

Comment: I dont think it has something to do with the driveletter/UNC-path. 
In the same script/procedure are the following lines which works great:

EXEC master..xp_CMDShell 'E:\FolderName\Batchcode\Copy_files.bat'
EXEC master..xp_CMDShell 'E:\FolderName\Batchcode\Rename_2.bat'